# Can't access frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, session, frontend-error

I can't access the frontend of my website, and when I look at the error report it gives me the following message:

```
Session data file is not created by your uid
```

I can access the admin panel without issue.

Can anyone please advise troubleshooting steps/a solution?

I have copied all the website and db files from a site working on a subdomain. I have updated env.php and the core config data to include the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

In believe this is caused by php-fpm not being able to write the session files. If you run the following

`chown -r user:group /path/to/sessions`

Replacing user and group with the ones that php-fpm uses and i cant remeber if path to sessions is under `/var/lib/php/session` or `magento/var/sessions`